# Unable to load web app

Tags: glassfish

Unable to load web application and console says the following

> InstallationHandlers.isRegistered() failed, reason:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

what does it means? Any Idea ?

Thanks,
Pramod

Answer (score 0):

Check your SSL settings. Try to turn off SSL and see if it helps.
And, as error msg says, check all paths to keystores and all certificate aliases.
I don't use glassfish - I just look at error message. PKIX is format of file, that contains certificates. All certificates, depending of CA (certificate authority), belong to different paths. Example: certificate from Thawte belongs to Thawte certficiate paths, cert from Verisign belong to Verisign path. So there is something wrong with certificate you use: it does not belong to any registered path, I think. One of the most popular ways to use certificates is SSL, so I presume this is your case. SSL settings should be somewhere in glassfish - google it. Or, maybe, you can make your application use unencrypted connections.

Comment: Glassfish server is running on Linux environment. So I asked my networking people to help me on this issue. Is that correct asking networking people to fix this issue? is there any other way we can fix the issue. As you said If I turn off the SSL, will it impact on application accessing through LAN? I am new to all these things.

Comment: I don't know, what do you mean by 'network people' (sounds scary), but i suppose all work must be done by glassfish administrator.